# kill background running applications in android programmatically

Tags: android

I am getting List of running background applications. To kill those applications by using:

```
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> listprocInfos =actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

if(RunningAppProcessInfo procInfos : listprocInfos ) {
    activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(procInfos.processName);
    // or activityManager.restartPackage(procInfos.processName);
}
```

But It is not working please help me.

Comment: Are you getting any error? How do you come to conclusion that it is not working?

Answer (score 2):

You must have special permissions to kill other applications programmatic.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

Also there is no grantee this will kill the process. If the device is rooted try finding the PID of the process and kill it via command.